# When I try to install any version of Python, it shows "specified path is unavailable"

Tags: python, path, failed-installation

When I try to install any version of Python, a dialogue box shows this message and interrupts the installation process:

[image]

Comment: You need to tell it to install to a directory that actually exists.

Comment: but it already exist, even if i change directory it show same message